# Javafx-2 tableview bindings with none text cells

Tags: binding, tableview, javafx-2

I would like to show a series of financial transactions in a TableView.
Each Transaction consists of a Date, a Description  and an Amount.

I can make this work using bindings if I treat all the cells as Text using the example shown in a reply to another question.  This allows in cell editing which is my goal.

But I can't get it to work on the date and amount columns, I think I need a separate cell factory for each cell type and a possibly a separate updateItem method but I'm stuck.

Any pointers to an example or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the DataFX project at:
http://www.javafxdata.org/
and specifically the cell factories like:
http://www.javafxdata.org/javadoc/org/javafxdata/control/cell/TextFieldCellFactory.html

DataFX contains custom cell factories for several data types, tables, lists and tree views. Assuming that for example your amount has a double type, you could write something similar like that in a subclass of TableColum
(replace ??? by the class name of the class that represents a row in your table):

```
setCellFactory(TextFieldCellFactory.<???, Number>forTableColumn(new Callback<String,Number>(){
        @Override
        public Number call(String newValueStr) {
            double newValue = Double.parseDouble(newValueStr);
            return newValue;    
    }));

setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<???, Number>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<???, Number> t) {
            double newValue = t.getNewValue().doubleValue();
            // do something with the double value the user entered here     
        }
    });
}
```

}

I hope that at least gives you some direction. I have left out Exception handling for clarity.